# Правила написания предлогов о и об

Tags: орфография

Есть ли четкое правило написания предлогов О и ОБ, в каких случаях пишется О, в каких ОБ?

Answer (score 9):

Большинство непроизводных предлогов в современном языке существует в нескольких вариантах (дублетах). Обычно эти варианты связаны с речевым окружением и зависят непосредственно от фонетических особенностей начала того слова, которое следует непосредственно за предлогом.

Что касается  вариантов **о** и **об**, то нас учили, что если последующее слово начинается с **а, о, и, у, э**, то употребляем предлог **об**. В остальных случаях (перед **е, ё, ю, я**, а также перед согласными) — предлог **о**.

Примеры такие: об **э**тике, но о [jэ]жевике (**е**жевике); об **а**збуке, но о [jа]сене (**я**сене); об **о**буви, но о [jо]жике (**ё**жике); об **у**лыбке, но о [jу]ности (**ю**ности).
Т. е. нужно помнить, что  так называемые йотированные гласные представляют собой сочетания двух звуков, один из которых — [**j**]: я [jа], ё [jо], ю [jу], е [jэ]. Следовательно, слово, начинающееся с букв Я, Ё, Ю, Е, на самом деле начинается с согласного звука.

Answer (score 2):

Правила есть. Но в полном виде они весьма сложные.
Полностью их можно найти в "Орфоэпическом словаре" под редакцией Аванесова, сопроводительная статья. Там разбору посвящено несколько абзацев, перепечатывать сюда нет никакой возможности. Обратите внимание, что о/об может управлять как винительным, так и предложным падежом, правила употребления о/об там разные.
Кстати, есть еще вариант "обо": "обо что", "обо всем".

Comment: А в электронном виде этого словаря нигде нет? Интересно бы почитать, а с бумаги нет возможности по физиологическим причинам.

Comment: @AndrePolykanine Мне трудно судить насчет физиологических причин (звучит странно), но если они вам не помешают читать сканы, то ищите здесь http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988-chitat-online.htm

Comment: Это картинки, да? Тогда таки помешают. Всё очень просто: я не вижу, поэтому использую программу экранного доступа и могу читать лишь текст, написанный буквами (не картинку). Просто подумал, что, может, вы знаете, где взять :).

Comment: @AndrePolykanine простите, не взял в расчет такой вариант. Смутило слово "физиологические". Сам словарь в подходящем для вас виде представить себе очень трудно. Там много всяких небуквенных символов, поэтому оцифровка практически невозможна. А вот сопроводительную часть я поищу, это обычный текст.

Comment: Спасибо заранее! А что за небуквенные символы, даже интересно? Если знаки ударения, то это всё прекрасно читается, например, в той же Википедии. Я вам больше скажу: даже выделение цветом на Грамоте.ру хорошо обрабатывается :). Не так удобно, но если знаешь, очень даже помогает выяснить ударение.

Comment: @AndrePolykanine http://www.twirpx.com/file/518753/  Вот ссылка, попробуйте. Это весь словарь в оцифровке **.pdf**. Регистрация для скачки бесплатная, у меня ушло две минуты на всё. Если будут сложности, пришлю сам файл. Там и со спецзначками разберетесь, если получится. Это фонетический алфавит (в том числе всякие надстрочные знаки) и символы для обозначения частей словарной статьи.

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от звука, следующего за предлогом. Если он гласный – используем "об". Логика в том, что произносить два гласных звука подряд сложно.

Примеры:

- *решение о дальнейшем сотрудничестве* (слово "дальнейшем" начинается с согласного звука);
- *сведения об их способностях* (слово "их" начинается с гласного звука);
- *история о еретике* (слово "еретик" начинается с гласной буквы, но с согласного звука);