# Какой предлог правилен - "о" или "об"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно сказать: "Не хочу о вас мараться" или "об вас"?

Answer (score 1):

**МАРАТЬСЯ**,  Разг. 1. Пачкаться, грязниться. М. сажей. **М. о грязный столб.**  2. Ввязываться в неприятную историю, какое-л. предосудительное дело.

О или ОБ [К Дню знаний или ко Дню знаний? | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?id=69)

**Думать о вас – только один предлог О в П.п.. Мараться о/об вас – оба предлога в В.п.**

1) Думаю, что лучше использовать вариант: **Не хочу о вас мараться.**

Предлог ОБ в большей степени разговорный, а предлог О – книжный. Для **переносного значения** слова "мараться" лучше подходит предлог О.

Также особого внимания требует **сочетание согласных Б+В** (губного и губно-зубного), которое в некоторых случаях может иметь просторечный или устаревший характер. Например, в современном языке: **обо всех**, но не "об всех". Раньше: Я начал расспрашивать **об всех** этих господах [А. Ф. Писемский.  (1855)]

2) Примеры: Вы заслужили пулю, но мы не хотим марать **о вас** руки. [К. С. Бадигин. Секрет государственной важности (1974)]

А так пишет народ на форумах: Нужны вы мне 100 лет, мараться **о вас** и оскорблять тем паче!

3) Но (**перед другими согласными)**: Да нужен ты, мараться **об тебя**…[Николай Коляда. (1989)]. И опять она поддакивала: «Да уж конечно… Мараться **об них**… » [Ирина Муравьева.  (1995)]

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, здесь лучше то, что вам проще выговорить. Я бы сказал "об вас", поскольку с местоимениями форма "об" употребляется чаще.

Все известные жесткие предписания по выбору конкретной формы нельзя признать общепринятыми, обычно они противоречат друг другу. Вот чтоб далеко не ходить.

[Правила написания предлогов о и об](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5240)
[Предлог об и обо](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33493)
[Предлог о/об](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47384)

Ни по одному из вопросов нет единого мнения.

Думаю, что причина подобной несогласованности в том, что не решен базовый вопрос, являются предлоги о/об/обо всего лишь фонетическими формами одного предлога, или же они лишь частично синонимичны и имеют разное значение. Я склоняюсь ко второму (по аналогии с приставками "о" и "об" (ср. *обить* и *оббить*, *осыпать* и *обсыпать*), если это так, обсуждать "как правильно" не всегда уместно, ибо в таком случае варианты несут или могут нести несколько разный смысл. Конкретно в ваших примерах это не столь заметно, но если сравнить "мараться о стенку" и "об стенку", то при желании можно найти стилистическую разницу. Но коли так, то она может быть и в переносном значении.

Все это укрепляет в мысли, что однозначно правильного варианта тут нет. Только фонетически более удобный.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить картину: см. "Об" в Большом толковый словаре http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%B1&all=x

Comment: @М_Г - Спасибо, видел я. Но Кузнецов все-таки далеко не авторитет в орфоэпии. Я, признаться, и по части "толковости" его не очень уважаю, но там хоть предмет формально соответствует названию, пришлось бы читаться. А вот когда он противоречит Зарве или, там, Аванесову (или игнорирует их), приходится выбирать. И мой выбор не в пользу Кузнецова. Здесь как раз тот случай. Если принципиально попробую найти у кого я видел вполне осмысленные предположения о частично разной семантике предлогов о/об. Может, это Аванесов и был.

Comment: Выговорить-то как раз проще "о вас"; другое дело, что с предлогом "об" доходчивее оказывается _падеж_ этих самых "вас" - вне контекста он не путается с предложным.

Comment: @Alex_ander *Выговорить-то как раз проще "о вас"* - "о вас" легче произнести только без паузы. "Авас".  Это противоречит моему фонетическому чутью. И, насколько могу судить, далеко не только моему. *вне контекста он не путается с предложным* - Тут согласен. Другое дело, что умудряются и в предложном это "об" вставить. Впрочем, все это - досужие разговоры, восприятие таких вещей заведомо субъективно.